# How do I make the JSTL core tags work in RAD6.0?

Tags: jsp, jstl, rad

I am using RAD 6.0, where I have put jstl.jar under the lib folder in my application. When I am using the JSTL tags, it does not give any copilation errors. But when I am trying to run the application, the core tags are not working.

Answer (score 0):

RAD 6 / WAS 6 is Servlet 2.4 targeted. Thus:

1. Ensure that you've included **both** `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar` of [JSTL 1.1](http://jakarta.apache.org/site/downloads/downloads_taglibs-standard.cgi) in webapp's classpath (the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder).
2. Ensure that you're declaring taglibs in top of JSP files as per [JSTL 1.1 tlddoc](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) (click any of libs to see them). E.g.

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
   ```

   Especially note *presence* of `/jsp` in path and also the *absence* of the `_rt` prefix in name.
3. Ensure you've declared `web.xml` as per Servlet 2.4 spec (and thus not as Servlet 2.3 or older).

   ```
   <web-app
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
       version="2.4">
   ```

Comment: I have both jstl as well as standard.jar, under my web app.
But after I have made the above mentioned change I am having following errors in web.xml.
1) Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "web-app".

Comment: 2) cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'taglib'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":description, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":display-name, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":icon, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":distributable, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":context-param, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":filter, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":filter-mapping, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":listener, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":servlet, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":servlet-mapping, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":session

Comment: -config, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":mime-mapping, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":welcome-file-list, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":error-page, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":jsp-config, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":security-constraint, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":login-config, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":security-role, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":env-entry, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":ejb-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":ejb-local-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":service-

Comment: ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":resource-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":resource-env-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":message-destination-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":message-destination, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":locale-encoding-mapping-list}' is expected. 

Am not sure what to do.

Comment: Ordering of the elements in `web.xml` is strict in Servlet 2.4. Easiest would be to have RAD autogenerate the `web.xml` for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the jstl.jar to the Java Build Path in the Project Properties of the particular project.

Be aware that Java Build Path and MANIFEST.MF (for runtime Classpath) can get out-of-sync at some point. Therefore it is better to use Rational Application Developer 7.0 or 7.5 which also support WebSphere Application Server 6.0.

Also, Rational Application Developer 6.0 is out-of-support already:
http://www-111.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycle/PLCDetail.wss?brand=rational&synkey=W170532D29019M02-L603472G19375Q17-M054243E02973V75&synkey=W170532D29019M02-L603472G19375Q17-R377236X92964B60&synkey=W170532D29019M02-T872435L09150T44-O941388U48112Q95&ibm-view=View+details

The postings on this site are my own and do not necessarily represent the positions, strategies, or opinions of IBM